# SPRING C3P0 - How to get all busy connection and cancel a specific connection

Tags: java, sql, spring, c3p0

I am using a connection pool and I can get connection through a DATASOURCE. I can get all number of connection by

`pool.getNumConnections(username, password))`
`pool.getNumBusyConnections(username, password))`
`pool.getNumIdleConnections(username, password))`
`pool.getNumBusyConnectionsAllUsers()`

Now, if my pool reached the `maxPoolSize`, will throw an error `an attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.`. I need to handle this connection and recover from it. My solution is to get the first connection and stop it then create a new connection from its slot to execute the new query. But I have no idea how to do that.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Increase max pool size and find out why your connections take that long.

Comment: I can't increase the max pool size. It should be what it is (6). The queries I am executing will return around 200k of rows so it sure took long time to execute. and I want to handle that.

Comment: Do you want calls to getConnection() to timeout when the pool is maxed out, or would you prefer clients simply wait for new Connections to become available? The easiest thing to do would be to set the c3p0 config param `checkoutTimeout` to zero, in which case you'll have no Exception to handle, backed-up clients will just wait until a Connection becomes available.

Comment: actually, I have that `checkoutTimeout` set to 30000. (Assume that the limit is reach and all connections contains a long query) after 30secs, It errors `an attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.` but after I run a another query, it will always show that error. I can't run any other quieries after that. I'm sorry I don't understant connection pooling absolutely.